# Dynamically sum table columns on each table (page) break

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I update  element using Javascript when printing big tables which break on each page when printing.

```
Example - One big table

Page 1 (A4 Paper)

+-----+-------+
| No. | Price |
+-----+-------+
|  1  |   200 |
|  2  |   300 |
+-----+-------+
+-------+-----+
| Total | 500 | (sum of Price column on Page 1)
+--------+----+

Page 2 (A4 Paper)

+-----+-------+
| No. | Price |
+-----+-------+
|  3  |   300 |
|  4  |   300 |
+-----+-------+
+-------+-----+
| Total | 600 | (sum of Price column on Page 2)
+--------+----+
```

I need to dynamically know where the table breaks on each page (on which No. row), and then sum it up at bottom of each page in **tfoot** element

Screenshot of my table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgBLz.png

Comment: JavaScript is maybe not what your are looking for...from my understanding that will be hard to do what's you expect...I will more go with another language as Java, PHP, Python,... After googlize it, it seems like some JS library exists to genereate docx (docx.js). Maybe you want to give it a try...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.